# Is it possible to restrict an SSRS report on Report Manager to one user at a time?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012, reportmanager

I have an SSRS report published to Report Manager, available to all Domain Users. The report's stored procedure executes a xp_cmdshell which outputs SQL data to an excel file in a shared file location. The issue is the report can't handle being run concurrently - anyone trying to run the report simultaneously with another user gets a blank file, or, worse, a file with missing data. I can't redevelop the solution right now, what I'm hoping to do is restrict the report to one user at a time, either within the SSRS report, via report manager config or the SharePoint link on our intranet (which users access the report by). Everything is on-prem.

I've tried the report config, RM config, our SharePoint developer and Google and none are helping. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have control over the schema / database? can you write to it? You could have a "Lock" field that each report run sets to true and then resets to false when done... (its pretty hacky and not robust to failure, but might be better than what you have.)

Comment: *Why* do you need to do this would be my question. This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: This really seems to be bad design in multiple ways. Why don't you let the user just export to excel and get it via browser download? You should really redesign your solution. Please give more details what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: Why is SQL Server even touching the Excel file? SSRS can generate Excel files and can even do that on a scheduled basis by way of Report Subscriptions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies. I know this is a really bad design - it was developed years ago by someone who had limited access to anything. It's also accessing a huge dataset and a simple SSRS report exporting to Excel wasn't sufficient. I'm trying to get the organisation to let me redevelop it using something more robust but atm we are moving to the cloud and redevelopment is on hold. So, for now I was just looking for a quick fix to the current dilemma - concurrent users. @Edward thanks for that tip, I'll have a look.